# T-SQL Recursive Query to show nested Tree structure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, recursion

I have the following 2 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [Names] 
    (
    [Id] INT PRIMARY KEY,
    [Name] VARCHAR(100)
    )

CREATE TABLE [Relationships]
    (
    [Parent] [int] REFERENCES [Names]([Id]), 
    [Child] [int] REFERENCES [Names]([Id])
    )

Sample Data:

INSERT [NAMES] VALUES (1,'FRANK')
INSERT [NAMES] VALUES (2,'JO')
INSERT [NAMES] VALUES (3,'MARY')
INSERT [NAMES] VALUES (4,'PETER')
INSERT [NAMES] VALUES (5,'MAY')

INSERT [RELATIONSHIPS] VALUES (1,2)
INSERT [RELATIONSHIPS] VALUES (2,3)
INSERT [RELATIONSHIPS] VALUES (4,2)
INSERT [RELATIONSHIPS] VALUES (5,4)
```

How to show a nested (tree) list of names including [Id], [Name] and [Level], where [Level] indicates the nest level from the top (Root: Level = 0; First children of Root: Level = 1; etc…)?
For instance, the result should be showing:

```
Level     Relationship
-----     ------------
2         FRANK <- JO
3         FRANK <- JO <- MARY
2         PETER <- JO
3         MAY <- PETER <- JO
```

Answer (score 0):

You might consider switching to [Hierarchical Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677173.aspx). TSQL supports it well enough and you don't need to 'reinvent the wheel'. This will make you queries easier in the long run.

[Go here for a nice tutorial on the subject.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677213.aspx)

Comment: Can you confirm Hierarchical Data in SQL supports multiple parents for a child?

Comment: Hierarchical Data only supports one parent per child. See [this form](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/bc9745ad-7508-4757-a7ab-71f40e465b3a/hierarchyid-multiple-parents-multiple-children-relation?forum=transactsql). That form includes some other options if you need multi-parent multi-child relationships

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
with Relatives as
(
    select n.Id, cast(n.Name as varchar(max)) Relationship, 0 [Level]
    from Names n
    where not exists
    (
        select *
        from Relationships r
        where n.Id = r.Child
    )

    union all

    select n.Id, p.Relationship + ' <- ' + n.Name Relationship, p.[Level] + 1 [Level]
    from Names n
    join Relationships r
        on n.Id = r.Child
    join Relatives p
        on r.Parent = p.Id
)

select Relationship, [Level]
from Relatives
```